# Colums validation gives error

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation

I want to create an input form in SharePoint.

In this form you have to select a date. It must be the date *2016/01/20* or *2016/01/27* (in my country it's called *20.01.2016* and *27.01.2016*. The column is called `Datum`). When you try another date, an error message, which I define should appear.

I tried this code:

```
=OR(Datum="20.01.2016";Datum="27.01.2016")
```

The Error message, which I defined, appears. But the problem is, it appears all the time. Even if I enter the correct date. 
What's wrong with this code?

Comment: If you are running different regional settings on the site, try to change the semicolon (;) to commas (,).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it in my German SharePoint 2013 on-prem environment, but maybe it is working in SPO as well.

The formular itself after you saved it looks like this:

[image]

`=ODER(Datum=DATWERT("20.01.2016");Datum=DATWERT("27.01.2016"))`

You can also use the english formular:

`=OR(Datum=DATEVALUE("20.01.2016");Datum=DATEVALUE("27.01.2016"))`

Assuming your "Datum" field is a Date type, then you need to compare dates to dates and not dates to strings. I think that's the reason.

The english formular will be translated into german after you saved it.

Comment: If my answer completly works for you you can also mark it as the answer to your question to help everbody which has the same problem.